# Any way to configure SIM unlock after leaving flight mode?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris, airplane-mode

I'm using an Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition phone, and I want to know if there is a way to configure how the phone unlock the SIM Cards when I leave the flight mode or another way to disable one SIM card without restart.

I had 2 SIM cards inserted into the phone (private & work) and I want to easily disable the work one when I go home. Now I have to restart my phone to leave locked the work SIM until the next day.

When I bought the phone and returned from flight mode, no SIM was automatically unlocked and I had to type the pin for the 2 SIM cards. With the new updates, the 2 SIM are automatically unlocked.

Is there any way to configure this?

Thanks in advance.